# Postgresql error more than one row returned by a subquery when I used trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am using trigger and function to insert values into another table.

I do have this table 
1)EXHIBITION

```
exhid   exhname             description    strtdate       enddate   status
101     The Famous          BLAH BLAH      2013-07-15   2013-10-13  SOON
102     York Exhibition     BLAH BLAH      2013-08-07   2014-01-19  End
103     Fine ART            BLAH BLAH      2014-09-26   2015-03-21  SOON
```

2)Works_Exhibitions

```
   alphid   numberid      exhid
    SCFI    1007          101
    SCBU    1008          101
    PAHF    1002          103
    PAHE    1003          103
    PASP    1004          103
```

and third empty table which has same attributes as Works_Exhibitions and name it Temp_works_exhibitions

```
alphid  numberid      exhid
```

I did create this function and trigger so once I update the status of any exhibition in the Exhibition table to be 'End', I would like to copy all the works of that exhibition to be in the new table Temp_works_exhibitions and then remove it from the Works_exhibition table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add2Temp_works_exhibitions() returns TRIGGER AS $updExhibStat$
BEGIN

IF(NEW.Status = 'End') THEN
INSERT INTO temp_works_exhibitions
select 

    Works_Exhibitions.alphID,
    Works_Exhibitions.numberID,
    Works_Exhibitions.exhID

from
    Works_Exhibitions
where
    Works_Exhibitions.exhID = (select Exhibitions.exhID from Exhibitions where  Exhibitions.Status = 'End');

delete from Works_Exhibitions where Works_Exhibitions.exhID = (select Exhibitions.exhID from Exhibitions where  Exhibitions.Status = 'End');

RETURN NEW;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;

$updExhibStat$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--CREATE TRIGGER updExhibStat AFTER UPDATE ON Exhibitions FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add2Temp_works_exhibitions();
```

When I test it first time it did work but when I tried to update a new exhibition I got this ERROR

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO temp_works_exhibitions
select 

    Works_Exhibitions.alphID,
    Works_Exhibitions.numberID,
    Works_Exhibitions.exhID

from
    Works_Exhibitions
where
    Works_Exhibitions.exhID = (select Exhibitions.exhID from Exhibitions where  Exhibitions.Status = 'End')"
PL/pgSQL function add2temp_works_exhibitions() line 5 at SQL statement
```

Any Idea how to fix this

Comment: The trivial way is to add `LIMIT 1` but the larger questions are: Why did you think the subquery would return ONE answer? and/or What do you want to do if there is not exactly ONE answer.

Comment: In short: use `EXISTS( ... )`

Comment: I did use EXISTS( ... ) but I am getting function exisit(boolean) does not exist

Comment: Since it is a trigger function you could replace `(select Exhibitions.exhID from Exhibitions ...` by `new.exhID` (assuming that Exhibition.exhID is a primary key)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I did fix the problem

I did add this command at the end of the function

```
UPDATE Exhibitions set Status = 'Expired' where Exhibitions.Status = 'End';
```

I guess it's not really a good design but I don't have another solution